# Calling beforeEach and afterEach with nested describe blocks

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I'm trying to get some logic to be called before and after each nested describe of a jasmine test suite I'm writing.

I have something like this right now:

```js
describe('Outer describe', function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
        login();
        someOtherFunc();
    });

    afterEach(function () {
        logout();
    });

    describe('inner describe', function () {
        it('spec A', function () {
                expect(true).toBe(true);
        });

        it('spec B', function () {
                expect(true).toBe(true);
        });
    });
});
```

I'm finding my functions in the `beforeEach` and `afterEach` are called for each `it` inside my inner describe. I only want these to be called once for each inner describe I have in the outer one.

Is this possible?

Comment: In case it helps someone. When I have nested describe blocks, using `beforeEach` in the top level describe will run the code before every test, including nested tests. I'm using vitest. You can test this with `beforeEach(() => console.error("HELLO"))` and read the output.

Answer (score 20):

To accomplish this I define a common function and then refer to it in the `beforeAll`/`afterAll` of each nested `describe`.

```
describe('Wrapper', function() {
  var _startup = function(done) {
    login();
    window.setTimeout(done, 150);
  };

  var _shutdown = function() {
    logout();
  };

  describe('Inner 1', function() {
    beforeAll(_startup);
    afterAll(_shutdown);
  });

  describe('Inner 2', function() {
    beforeAll(_startup);
    afterAll(_shutdown);
  });

  describe('Inner 3', function() {
    beforeAll(_startup);
    afterAll(_shutdown);
  });
});
```

It seems to be cleanest solution available.

Answer (score 9):

I think you should use 'beforeAll' and 'afterAll',for specs inside a describe. following is taken from jasmine website : http://jasmine.github.io/2.1/introduction.html

> The beforeAll function is called only once before all the specs in
>   describe are run, and the afterAll function is called after all specs
>   finish. These functions can be used to speed up test suites with
>   expensive setup and teardown.
>
> However, be careful using beforeAll and afterAll! Since they are not
>   reset between specs, it is easy to accidentally leak state between
>   your specs so that they erroneously pass or fail.

Comment: Thanks but I have seen this documentation already and it doesn't help in my scenario

Comment: I know it's 4 years late but for future readers what @Ram Pasala is saying is exactly what one would need. That or you can put `beforeEach` outside of the parent describe.